# Threes.js Raycaster not intersecting with custom vertex shader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm implementing a particules systems with dedicated Vertex shader.
Here a code example: https://jsfiddle.net/dthevenin/7arntcog/

I do use a Raycaster to do mouse picking and make possible to interact with one particule.

The code works as expected until I try to change the position of a vertex from the Vertex Shader.
For instance in that example, I do pass a time value as an Uniform, and modify the x position with that time's value.

```
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position.x + time, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
```

Then the Raycaster failed to calculate the intersection.

To see the issue, uncomment the line 86, then clicking on a particule does not work.

What is wrong with that code / that solution?

Comment: Since the the Raycaster is not aware about what happening in the GPU, the solution is to implement a picking based on a offscreen texture. Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/q4b0mog8/

Answer (score 2):

When you use the raycaster intersection method, you're testing against the original `geometry.attributes.position` vertex values. This calculation takes place in your CPU **before** they get displaced in your vertex shader. These values don't know what's going on in the GPU, so any vertex-shader position changes won't reflect in your raycasting.

If you need to displace your vertices and also perform raycasting after this displacement, you'll have to constantly update the `position` attribute so the changes are accessible both in CPU and GPU calculations. [Here's an official example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_dynamic) of this method in action. You can see the source code in the button in the corner, but here's the relevant code to make your geometry dynamic.

```js
const position = geometry.attributes.position;
position.usage = THREE.DynamicDrawUsage;

for ( let i = 0; i < position.count; i ++ ) {

    const y = 35 * Math.sin( i / 2 );
    position.setY( i, y );

}
```

It's definitely less efficient to do it in the CPU than in the vertex shader, but it's the only easy solution if you need to do raycasting.

Comment: thanks for your comment. As you say, the raycaster is not aware of what is happening in the GPU side.
I went to a solution based on a rendering into an offscreen texture.
That works perfectly.
Here an example https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/q4b0mog8/ implemented by Paul West.